# stuck at grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I was trying to have dual boot windows10 and ubuntu 18.4, something goes wrong and I have deleted the ubuntu partition, and now stucked at grub rescue after first reboot, all the filesystem showing unknown, tried every single partition, what can I do now?

tried to install windows 10 again from here with bootable pendrive, but this isn't working either, (BIOS setting is all ok still not booting to pendrive)

Comment: have you tried the boot repair disk? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: for this I have to have a working ubuntu os right? I installed ubuntu properly, that is all, couldn't open twice,  stucked at grub after this